# How to set spacing between collectionview cells in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, collectionview

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nGKh.png

1. How do i set a spacing between the rows in the collection view cell. As you can tell by the picture provided, they are way too close.
2. Since they are too close the text in the label cant break into 2 lines and im trying to figure out how to do that, but cant find anything as everything i search for is in objective -c and im only a beginner in swift.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you for your time!

Comment: Do you mind if all the cells have the same size or do you need cell sizes to be based on content (i.e. cells with multi-line titles are taller than those with single-line labels)?

Comment: I want them to be the same size however i want the labels under them to break into 2 lines if they are too long to fit onto one line.  The inset delegation did not work (suggestion below) . Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Change the top, left, bottom and top insets as needed after implementing this layout delegate method:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0)
}
```

Comment: Very useful to implement shadows in the cell (ContentView)!!!

Answer (score 0):

In Your viewDidLoad add this code:-

```
if let layout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout{

         // set the section insets as you required..
         layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 5)
         // set the line spacing according to your requirement
         layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5       
 }
```